# How to delete IPv6 DNS Servers via command line?

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, tcp, netsh

I can successfully delete IPv4 DNS Servers via command line on a Windows Server 2019 with the following command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsserver "My Ethernet" all
```

After this command I execute `ipconfig /all` and see the following IPv6 DNS Servers show up (which were not there before):

> ```
> ...
> DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
>                                     fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
>                                     fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
> ...
> ```

I've (naively) tried the following commands neither worked:

```
netsh interface ipv6 delete dnsserver "My Ethernet" all
netsh interface delete dnsserver "My Ethernet" all
```